# JW video's do not play on Android 4.* with Android Mobile SDK 2.4.2

Tags: android, jwplayer

There are a lot of complaints about Android 4.* (Android API 19) . (see attached screenshot) . These users complain they can't play the videos. I'm using JW Android Mobile SDK 2.4.2+159. What are your recommendations for fixing this (updating the JW SDK ? , or making some specific changes to the Android project? )  - apart from telling users to update to Android 5.*  and higher.

[image]